# How to create pugjs components?

Tags: javascript, pug, tailwind-css

Is there a possiblitiy of creating pugjs components where I can call the component like `x-button Sign In`

The component will look like this

```
button(class="py-3 px-8 rounded-lg inline-flex justify-center items-center font-semibold text-base leading-6 tracking-wide") #{text}
```

Similar to this concept [Laravel component](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/2.x/resources/views/components/button.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [Pug mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) are for:

```
// declare the mixin
mixin x-button
  button.py-3.px-8.rounded-lg.inline-flex.justify-center.items-center.font-semibold.text-base.leading-6.tracking-wide
    if block
      block

// use the mixin
+x-button Sign In
```

Comment: Sean quick question: does mixin have to be inserting in the same file where you going to be using it or can it in separate file and extended to a file if so how do you extend it to another file?

Comment: @NicoTravassos You can put it in a separate file and then `include` that file in your root template or wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The Pug equivalents of components are [template inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) and [includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html). Includes would work for your use case:

```
//- includes/button.pug
button(class="py-3 px-8 rounded-lg inline-flex justify-center items-center font-semibold text-base leading-6 tracking-wide") #{text}
```

```
//- some-page.pug
//- index.pug
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    - var text = 'some-button-text'
    include includes/button.pug
```

Comment: Thank you Zac wish there was a better method like `x-button blah` but this looks like custom feature only.

Comment: The Pug equivalent of components are [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html)

Comment: @Sean thanks, I totally forgot mixins even exist! Your answer is the correct one.